# How to make the translate transform start from the element?

Tags: jquery, html, sass

I have implemented a simple swoop in animation in `CSS`. This animation is triggered on the button click. I am satisfied with the result but I can make it much better. I want the text which swoops in to start from the button element itself rather than coming all the way from the edge of the page. I tried changing the translate properties but I didn't had any luck. I was wondering if anyone could give me some suggestions on how to fix it and also it would be great if the code can be optimized to use `SASS/SCSS`.

EDIT: Updated the code with SCSS:

Here is the code for the animation:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swoop-in">
  <div class="swoop-in-content">
    PRETTY NEAT TRANSITION BLAH BLAH..
  </div>
</div>

<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
 swoop-in {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   top: 140px;
   width: 220px;
   margin-left: -30px;
   &.show .swoop-in-content {
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
   }
   .swoop-in-content {
      transform: translateX(100%);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all .5s ease;
   }
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #9c89f7;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('.swoop-in').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Here is the [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/applecool/pen/zjjxPr) for it.
Updated [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/applecool/pen/jxxZMP) with SCSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one is matching for your needs `https://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/MGGBvV` you can just adujst the percentage of the translate property if you want to change the effect

## UPDATED

Safari have a prolem with `transition: all` we always should specify what we want to transition so the solution is

```
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), opacity .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
```

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.swoop-in').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.swoop-in {
  transform: translateX(45%);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  top: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), opacity .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  z-index: -1;
}
.swoop-in.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn {
  text-align: right;
}

.toggle {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
}
.toggle:hover {
  background-color: #9c89f7;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swoop-in">
  PRETTY NEAT TRANSITION BLAH BLAH..
</div>

<div class="btn">
  <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get it what exactly that it's not working ? if you toggle on the button the text will appear and disappear as you were looking for

Comment: It isn’t toggling the text. I don’t see the text at all.

Comment: I just checked it now again its totally working fine and even in codepen https://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/MGGBvV its also ok

Comment: Aaah. it is not working on Safari... It is working on Firefox, Chrome, IE 11 & Edge. I am assuming it's because of the cubic-bezier. I am not sure though. Any idea?

Comment: Hey Adel, did you get a chance to try it on the Safari?

Comment: @ShellZero yes i have fixed it and already updated in the post and codepen as well in safari when you say `transition:all .2s ease-in-out` whatever the function is its behaving different we should specify what property we want to transition so i fixed and the fix is to use    `transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), opacity .4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94); `

Comment: Cool. But If you move the button to your left a bit, you can actually see the text coming from the edge.. Anyways, thank you for your time and effort :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Assume this is not the best solution, but you could play with it to make fancier (depending on content you'll have in that animated div).
https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/oddpZY
Instead of transitioning position property I changed initial `width: 0px;` to the desired one and positioned it at the left edge of the button. To be able to do this we need set button size as well. `overflow: hidden` make the text in transitioning div look not so weird, but still is not perfect.

Comment: Cool :) Thanks for the attempt. It does give me a great idea of how to approach it. Will accept the answer after 24 hours so that it gives enough time for any other answers :)